# SQLite exception while trying to delete row

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I'm getting error:

> android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near ":BE": syntax error
>   (code 1): , while compiling: DELETE FROM device WHERE
>   address=C4:BE:84:18:D5:A5

while trying to remove row from sqlite database.

```
public int removeDevice(String address) {
  open();
  int removedId = database.delete(MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_DEVICE
                , MySQLiteHelper.KEY_ADDRESS +  "=" + address, null);
  close();

  return removedId;
}
```

I can't figure out what's wrong.

Comment: is `address` a string? Strings need to be quotted

Comment: @VladMatvienko Yes, indeed: It's a MAC address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
int removedId = database.delete(MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_DEVICE
            , MySQLiteHelper.KEY_ADDRESS +  "= ?",new String[] {address});
```

Answer (score 2):

use address with single quotes

```
DELETE FROM device WHERE address='C4:BE:84:18:D5:A5'
```

Comment: Wrose answer from both Rahul Giradkar's and Divyesh's answer

Answer (score 1):

use this :

sqLiteDatabase.delete("Table", "row= ?", new String[]{String.valueOf(value)});